# Check primary keys values

Tags: sql, sqlite

These are tables in SQLite: `especie_similar`

```
CREATE TABLE especie_similar (
    id_especie INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_similar INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        id_especie,
        id_similar
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        id_especie
    )
    REFERENCES especie (id_especie) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        id_similar
    )
    REFERENCES especie (id_especie) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And `especie` table:

```
CREATE TABLE especie (
    id_especie     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                           NOT NULL,
    nombre_especie VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    cient_especie  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    desc_especie   TEXT,
    nidificacion   TEXT    NOT NULL,
    dimorfismo     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    genero_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    endemismo_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    abundancia_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        genero_id
    )
    REFERENCES genero (id_genero),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        endemismo_id
    )
    REFERENCES endemismo (id_endemismo),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        abundancia_id
    )
    REFERENCES abundancia (id_abundancia) 
);
```

My situation: Table `especie` has multiple datas and I want to insert in `especie_similar` ids from table `especie`.

1. How can i code a trigger or sql statement checking if `id_especie` and `id_similar` are not equals?
2. How can i code to retrieve all `especie`s distinct of target id
   (ex: table `especie_similar` has `id_especie`=1 and `id_similar`=2
   indicating that species id 1 is similar to another species id 2 but
   cannot insert `id_especie`=2 and `id_similar`=1 due to previous
   duplicate data)?

Thanks and sorry my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

For question #1 you can use a standard SQL constraint:

```
create table especie_similar (
  ...
  check (id_especie <> id_similar) -- your condition here
);
```

For question #2 you can use a standard "Recursive CTE". See [SQLite WITH Clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html). Example:

```
with recursive node as (
  select id from especie_similar 
    where id_especie = 123 -- first node criteria here
  union all
  select s.id_especie
    from node n
    join especie_similar s on s.id_similar = n.id
)
select * from node;
```